# Javascript - Document Query Selector

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select the job posting titles and the href for the job postings. Then return response.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Website:  https://epyz.fa.us2.oraclecloud.com/hcmUI/CandidateExperience/en/sites/CX_1/requisitions?location=Jacksonville,%20FL,%20United%20States&locationId=300000002870977&locationLevel=city&mode=location&radius=25&radiusUnit=MI

Here is my last attempt:

```js
  function ExecuteScript() {
    let response = '';
    document.querySelectorAll('h2[data-bind="text: job.title"]').forEach((element, i) => {
      response += element.innerHTML + '\\t' + location.host + element.getAttribute('href') + '\\n';
    });
    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inspect how page structure looks like: each list element (job post) is list item (`li`) with full-size link (`a`) inside it. Also each item contain `h2` header that represent post title:

```
li -> a
   -> div -> h2
```

So *to grab both title and link* you can iterate through list items and search for target children elements:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li.job-tile')).map(element => ({
 title: element.querySelector('h2.job-tile__title').innerText,
 link: element.querySelector('a.job-tile__show').href
}))
```

Where

```
li.job-tile        - list item, post tile actually
h2.job-tile__title - header, post title
a.job-tile__show   - link, post page URL
```

This snippet will return array of objects with title & links like this:

```js
[
  {
    title: 'Application Engineer (Custom Solutions)', 
    link: 'https://epyz.fa.us2.oraclecloud.com/hcmUI/Candidat…nLevel=city&mode=location&radius=25&radiusUnit=MI'
  },
  {
     title: 'Intern - Custom Solutions (Information Systems)', 
     link: 'https://epyz.fa.us2.oraclecloud.com/hcmUI/Candidat…nLevel=city&mode=location&radius=25&radiusUnit=MI'
  },
  ...
]
```

Also should be noticed that feed you provided contains paggination (as infinite scroll) so grabbing methods like this one will parse *only visible* posts (loaded), not all of them.

Comment: I am trying to return a response as I am storing this as a variable in Microsoft Power Automate Desktop. Is it possible to use the format I was using above? I tried using yours and it returned an empty result for me. Hopefully that makes sense?